# how to make python script restart itself when it stops because of error

Tags: python, error-handling

I have a script that has to run 24/7. the script reads some emails and sends some queries to an API.
sometimes the internet connection faces some problem and the script stops working. because of circumstances I cannot just use try/except and I need to restart the whole script.
so is there any way to make the script run itself from the start when faces some errors?

Comment: Well if you cant catch the error how is the script suppose to know to start again? maybe you can look at an external tool that looks if the script is running and if its not it will start it

Comment: The only non-OS-specific way I can think of would be to have a completely separate "controller" script that watched over the other script and restarted it as necessary.

Comment: `supervisord` can probably do this for you

Comment: Use a try except, that's what they are for.

Comment: what if you put all code inside `try/except` - to catch every error and this you would put inside `white True` to run all code again and again. If you have problem with connection than maybe you need to set `timeout`